# Comparing values in data frames in r and giving a vote depending on the highest count

Tags: r

I am new to R,
 have a data frame say data, looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
    predicted = c(15, 15, 15, 8, 15),
    actual    = c(18, 18, 16, 6, 18)
)
```

I need to check the number of times actual value say 18 has been predicted 15 and also 16 has been predicted 15, and based on the count of the prediction, I can say its better to call 18 a 15 as the count of prediction says, the higher the better. I tried it in excel, but its too much for the records, any way to do it in R, I know its just a countif, but cannot go beyond the loops for iterating the data frame. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table` to find the frequency

```
table(data)["15",]
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but it wont work, consider my data frame with columns predicted and actual, and the values which i mentioned above, now, i need to know the count of actual values that have been predicted what value. say 18 is actual and it is predicted 15 3 times and also 13 once, so on seeing this count i can infer that 18 should be predicted as 15. There are other values as well, starting from 1 to 20 for predicted, similarly for actual. These are labels which have been given.

Answer (score 0):

@akrun is correct that `table()` will give you the information you want.

```
counts <- table(data)
counts
#          actual
# predicted 6 16 18
#        8  1  0  0
#        15 0  1  3
```

So you can see when 15 is predicted, 18 is the most common actual value. To just get the most common actual values for each predicted, you can use `apply()` to find the highest value for each row.

```
winners <- apply(counts, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which.max)
winners
# 8 15 
# 1  3
```

The `which.max()` function returns the index of the highest value, and since we applied it by row, that would be the column number. So now you can use that information to store the mapping from predicted to likely actual in a `data.frame`.

```
prediction_map <- data.frame(
  from = as.integer(rownames(counts)),
  to   = as.integer(colnames(counts)[winners])
)
prediction_map
#    from to
# 1    8   6
# 2   15  18
```

Row and column names are character vectors, so they had to be converted to integers.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nathan and akrun. Appreciate your help.